# Why does CGRectContainsPoint cause error when determining overlap between two views?

Tags: objective-c, cgrect, cgpoint

Alright. I am new to objective-c, and I am trying to detect two views overlapping. I originally used `CGRectContainsRect` (which worked perfectly) but noticed that this calls true even if the views barely overlap. However, because the views are small, I only want the condition to be true if they heavily overlap. So, I am trying to use `CGRectContainsPoint` instead, where the point I check is the center of the second view.

Making this change is causing me some issues. Here is my whole if statement (though I have isolated the issue to the `CGRectContainsPoint` part:

```
NSDictionary *dictInQ = masterDict[n];
UIView *overlapV = dictInQ[@"view"];
NSNumber *overlapB = dictInQ[@"hiddenBool"];
//if it's not itself and they intersect and they are in the same column and both views are not hidden
if (overlapV != colorV && CGRectContainsPoint([overlapV frame], CGPointMake(colorV.center.x, colorV.center.y)) && startLocation == overlapV.frame.origin.x && [colorB intValue]!=1 && [overlapB intValue]!=1)
```

Originally when I used `CGRectContainsRect` I used `[overlapV frame]` and `[colorV frame].` Now I am attempting to use the `overlapV` view and check if it contains the center of view `colorV.` I have tried replacing `CGPointMake(colorV.center.x, colorV.center.y)` with `colorV.center` to no avail, and I have read documentation on CGRectContainsPoint and CGPointMake and examined similar questions.

What really puzzles me is that there is no error shown with this if statement line. It compiles fine, and when the CGRectContainsPoint should be evaluating true from the simulator, Xcode's error points to the first line executed in the if statement (though this line isn't what's causing problems either; I tried commenting it out and it just raises the error at the next line instead). Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

**Update**: here is a screenshot of the views when overlapping enough to cause the CGRectContainsPoint to correctly evaluate to true (the trouble is that it also causes an error on the proceeding line).

[image: Update: here is a screenshot of the views when overlapping enough to cause the CGRectContainsPoint to correctly evaluate to true (the trouble is that it also causes an error on the proceeding line).]

**Update**: To clarify, the breakpoint always happens on whatever line is called just after the `CGRectContainsPoint` passes (regardless of what I change the line to be). For instance, in my most recent test, the breakpoint highlighted line `NSLog(@"start");` and said `Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1,` but no output was printed to the console like a typical error message.

**Big Update**: Now to my astonishment, changing the CGRectContainsPoint back to the original, working, `CGRectContainsRece([overlapV frame], [colorV frame])` now doesn't work. However, the difference is that the program doesn't break when it should evaluate to `True`; it just keeps running like the if statement never should have been called.

Comment: What do you mean by "the trouble is that it also causes an error on the proceeding line"?

Comment: Are you drawing the circles? Or are they images?

Comment: show your breakpoints

Comment: @lnafziger Xcode shows the breakpoint to be whatever line of objective-c comes directly after the ``CGRectContainsPoint`` check returns true. In the screenshot in my answer, the breakpoint points to ```NSLog(@"start");`` (which there is nothing wrong with).

Comment: @uchuugaka the circles are being drawn from the views. I use ``view.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;`` for each view. And I have updated my answer to include breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
I think that I missed the main point of your question earlier.  A breakpoint is not an error, but simply a way to pause the execution of the program so that you can look at memory and step through the program line by line.  To get rid of it, simply click the breakpoint symbol to the left of the line of code that has it:

[image]

Or you can click the "continue program execution" button at the bottom:

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
Just to make debugging easier, I would suggest re-writing your if statement like this:

```
if (overlapV != colorV)
{
    // CGPointMake is not required here because a view's center is already a CGPoint.
    // Note that it won't cause a problem, it just isn't needed.
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([overlapV frame], colorV.center))
    {
        if (startLocation == overlapV.frame.origin.x)
        {
            if ([colorB intValue] != 1)
            {
                if ([overlapB intValue] != 1)
                {
                    // All are true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can step through one line at a time and see for sure which line is the problem.  The `CGRectContainsPoint` looks right though.  If it turns out to actually be the problem, please post a picture of what the views look like when this should be returning true.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I expanded the if statement as you demonstrated, and the breakpoint again pointed to whatever line followed the ``CGRectCointainsPoint`` check (I changed this line to simply ``NSLog(@"start");`` and it still was the breakpoint). However, this check clearly works; when the views do not overlap enough for one center to intersect another view, there is no problem and sim continues running as expected. I have updated my post to include a photo of the intersected views when the statement correctly evaluates to true, but causes an error.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This, indeed, worked! I am now confused as to why CGRectContainsRect no longer works, but if J cannot find a solution through my own efforts, I'll open a new question.